# Query for values

Tags: c#, linq

Declarations and entries in two_Dict dictionary is created as given:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>two_Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> list; 

if (!two_Dict.TryGetValue(d.ToString(), out list))
{
    two_Dict.Add( d.ToString(), list = new List<string>());
    list.Add(possibility_cell_list[0]);
    list.Add(possibility_cell_list[1]);
}
```

Sample entries in `two_Dict`:

```
two_Dict["5"] Count = 2 [0]: "A2"  [1]: "D2"
two_Dict["6"] Count = 2 [0]: "A2"  [1]: "D2"
```

I am looking to form a linq query to get the keys which have the same list entries in the dictionary `two_Dict`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fairly simple expression with linq:

```
var keys = from kvp1 in two_dict
           where two_dict.Any(kvp2 => kvp2.Key != kvp1.Key
               && kvp2.Value.SequenceEqual(kvp1.Value))
           select kvp1.Key;
```

However, this does not give the best performance as it will search through the entire dictionary `n` times, where `n` is the number of entries in the dictionary.

You can get slightly better performance if you only look at the items that have already been looked at so far. This way, on average you only go through half of the dictionary `n` times, so it's theoretically twice as fast. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a good way to do this purely using linq.

```
public static IEnumerable GetDuplicates(IDictionary<string, List<string>> dict)
{
    var previousItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>(dict.Count);
    var matchedItems = new List<bool>();
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
    {
        var match = previousItems.Select((kvp2, i) => Tuple.Create(kvp2.Key, kvp2.Value, i)).FirstOrDefault(t => kvp.Value.SequenceEqual(t.Item2));
        if (match != null)
        {
            var index = match.Item3;
            if (!matchedItems[index])
            {
                yield return match.Item1;
                matchedItems[index] = true;
            }
            yield return kvp.Key;
        }
        else
        {
            previousItems.Add(kvp);
            matchedItems.Add(false);
        }
    }
}
```

You would call the function like this:

```
var keys = GetDuplicates(two_dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> two_Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            var keyIndex = two_Dict.Keys.AsEnumerable()
                .Select((x, i) => new { index = i, value = x })
                .ToList();

            var result = (from key1 in keyIndex
                          from key2 in keyIndex
                          where key1.index > key2.index 
                          where AreEqual(two_Dict[key1.value],two_Dict[key2.value])
                          select new {key1 = key1.value, key2 = key2.value}).ToList(); 
        }
        static bool AreEqual<T>(List<T> x, List<T> y)
        {
            // same list or both are null
            if (x == y)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // one is null (but not the other)
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // count differs; they are not equal
            if (x.Count != y.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }
            x.Sort();
            y.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!x[i].Equals(y[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

All linq, no duplicate result but also, be careful, no null checks:

```
            var res = from k1 in dict.Keys
                from k2 in dict.Keys
                where string.Compare(k1, k2) == -1 && 
                dict[k1].Count == dict[k2].Count && !dict[k1].Any(x => !dict[k2].Contains(x)) && !dict[k2].Any(x => !dict[k1].Contains(x))
                select new { k1, k2 };
```

Comment: thanks. I am trying to  add entries of dict[k1] to "res" by select new {k1, k2, dict[k1]}. it gives me an error "invalid anonymous type member declarator".  What is the issue here?

Comment: try new {k1, k2, dictval = dict[k1]}